# Separate list into two equal parts with slices

Tags: python

I need to write a function that splits any list into two equal parts. If length of list is even, I want just split it it two parts, and if length of the list is odd, I want to ignore central element.

```
So [1,2,3,4,5,6] => [1,2,3] and [4,5,6]
and [1,2,3,4,5] => [1,2] and [4,5]
```

I tried to do the following way:

```
list = [1,100,50,-51,1,1]
s = len(list)/2
left = list[s+1:]
right = list[:s]
```

But this approach doesnt work both for even and odd lengths. 
Is there a way to use slices for this purpose or there is no way and it's better to use loops/iterations?

Comment: I think you reversed left and right...

Comment: What is `x`, on the line `s = len(x)/2`?

Comment: @Kevin this is old code, sorry. Here x = list.

Comment: Please do not use Python keywords to name your variables (here `list`)

Comment: Yes, used 'list' name only here by mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `divmod` on the length of the list and 2. Right slice is taken from sum of the quotient and the remainder:

```
lst = [1,100,50,-51,1,1]

s = divmod(len(lst), 2)
left = lst[:s[0]]
right = lst[sum(s):]
```

Comment: Didn't downvoted it, but loooks like this approach doesn't work right for odd lists: f([1,100,50,-51,1]) -> [170]: ([-51, 1], [1, 100, 50])

Comment: @Paul If it didn't work I wouldn't have posted. You should try it out

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps others did because `x` is undefined, and it is more readable this way: `quotient, remainder = divmod(len(lst), 2)` `left = lst[:quotient]` `right = lst[quotient+remainder:]`

Comment: @Guillaume Thanks for eye. Copied from my terminal

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
length = len(list)
half = int(length/2)
first_half = list[:half]
second_half = list[length-half:]
```

The trick here is cutting the decimal off of half when it's odd

Comment: Works too! Thanks!

Comment: I suggest `length // 2` instead of `int(length/2)`

Answer (score 2):

How about using negative indexing on the right half?

```
def separate(seq):
    s = len(seq)/2
    left = seq[:s]
    right = seq[-s:]
    return left, right

print separate([1,2,3,4,5,6])
#result: ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
print separate([1,2,3,4,5])
#result: ([1, 2], [4, 5])
```

Comment: Best answer IMHO, just beware of the `/` operator that has different behavior depending on python version

Comment: Good observation. For version inter-compatibility, consider using the `//` operator.

Comment: @Guillaume: Heck, it has different behaviors within Py2 depending on whether `from __future__ import division` is in effect. I tend to use `//` when appropriate in all Python code, whether it's intended for Py2 or Py3 (it's supported with or without the `__future__` import).

Answer (score 0):

`A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 B = A[:len(A)/2]
 C = A[len(A)/2:]`

If you want a function:

`def split_list(a_list):
     half = len(a_list)/2
     return a_list[:half], a_list[half:]
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
B, C = split_list(A)`

If you don't care about the order...

`def split(list):

    return list[::2]
    return list[1::2]`

list[::2] gets every second element in the list starting from the 0th element.
list[1::2] gets every second element in the list starting from the 1st element.

Comment: But when A is [1,2,3,4,5], C is [3,4,5]. OP wanted it to be just [4,5].